# Keil uVision (C51 compiler), what is meaning of unary operator "!"?

Tags: c, embedded, keil, c51

I'm programming with Keil uVision 4.

I have some code like this:

```
sbit X = P3 ^ 3; // X is third bit of P3 register

...

    while (1) {
      X = !X; // X equals not X ?!

      if (X == 0)
        printf("0");
      else
        printf("1");
    }
```

I can control `` `P3^3 `` generic input pin, because on this pin i've got a PIR (pulse infrared sensor). It gives me 1 on that line when it is blinking, 0 when it is sleeping.

when `P3^3` is pulled-up to `1`,
output is (as expected) `10101010101010..`

When it is still to 0,
output is (as not expected) `0000000000000..`

The behaviour I'm obtaing is that I described above, considering that `sbit X` is setted/unsetted by PIR..

So the question is, what is the meaning of the operator `!` in the Keil C51 compiler?

Comment: The documentation states that an `sbit` cannot be declared inside a function, so I am also assuming that this code fragment is elided?  It isn ormal to indicate that with an elipsis (`...`)

Comment: Just to be clear, it might be helpful to describe the `expected` output when the input is low, since on analysis I think it is behaving *correctly* (i.e. as coded) given the hardware and the semantics of the `sbit` language extension.

Comment: yes the scope is the global one.
i'm expecting pretty much the same output that i had when line was high.
Pratically, I was thinking that `!` is the same of `~`.

Comment: The expression `X = !X` changes P3.3 from an input to an output and vice versa. X is a reference to the pin, not an independent variable in memory.

Comment: Regarding being clear regarding the output, I expected you to modify the question rather than comment on it.

Comment: I'm sorry, Clifford, I'm doing it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Keil C51, to quote the [manual](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_sbit.htm):

> The sbit type defines a bit ***within*** a special function register (SFR)

So you are not declaring a variable X and reading it once before the loop, rather you are defining a *reference* to P3.3, and reading it's state on every iteration of the loop.  That is to say that X is a reference to the hardware I/O pin register, not a variable.

Despite appearances `sbit` is not a simple `typedef` alias and the `^` is not a bitwise XOR operator. Rather it defines a reference to a bit addressable register.  Assigning `X` writes to the hardware register - the behaviour is then defined by the hardware in this case rather than the language. The ability to apparently change the value of X when it is externally pulled high, I am guessing is in the nature of the GPIO hardware rather than any strange behaviour of the `!` operator. Check the hardware documentation for I/O pin behaviour, but I am guessing again that pulling it high makes the pin output-capable

To get the behaviour (I imagine) you expect you would code it thus:

```
sbit p = P3 ^ 3; // p is third bit of P3 register


...
int X = p ; // get p's current value

while (1) {
  X = !X; // X equals not X ?!

  if (X == 0)
    printf("0");
  else
    printf("1");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being not clear, on P3^3 i've got a PIR (pulse infrared sensor). It gives me 1 on that line when it is blinking, 0 when it is sleeping. The behaviour I'm obtaing is that I described above, considering that `sbit X` is setted/unsetted by PIR.

Comment: @FilippoLauria: I was referring the MCU GPIO hardware rather then the hardware you have connected to the pin. I believe that on 8051, a port is configured as an input by writing zero to it, which allows it to be asserted externally.  You write 1 to the pin to set it as an input, thereafter you should only read it - you are writing to it in the expression `X = !X`, so you are toggling it between an input and an output in the while loop.  As I said, check the documentation for your MCU.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it means the same thing it means in standard C. `!x` evaluates to `1` if `x==0`, or to `0` otherwise. The result is of type `int`.

If you're looking for a bitwise complement that inverts *all* the bits, you want the `~` operator.

**UPDATE :**

There's more to it than that; see [Clifford's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176990/827263).

Comment: I think that c51 is an extension of standard C. If what you said is right, why compiler doesn't give me an error (or a warning)  when I'm trying to assign an `int` to a `sbit` ?

Comment: @FilippoLauria: I don't know; quite possibly I'm wrong. I'm familiar with C, not with Keil C51. Do you get a warning when you explicitly assign an `int` value to an `sbit`?

Comment: I've tried `( int x = 1; sbit y = P3^3; ... y = x; )` no warnings are triggered off. Maybe is like you said, and for some reason unknown to me, the behaviour is, in my opinion, strange.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Assigning a value to an sbit changes the state of the pin referenced by the sbit.  I have linked to the documentation of sbit in my answer.